# How to expose my pod to the internet and get to it from the browser?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, cluster-computing, kubernetes

first of all I downloaded kubernetes, kubectl and created a cluster from aws (`export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=aws; wget -q -O - https://get.k8s.io | bash`
)

I added some lines to my project circle.yml to use circleCI services to build my image.

To support docker I added:

```
machine:
  services:
    - docker
```

and to create my image and send it to my artifacts I added:

```
deployment:
    commands:
      - docker login -e admin@comp.com -u ${ARTUSER} -p ${ARTKEY} docker-docker-local.someartifactory.com
      - sbt -DBUILD_NUMBER="${CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM}" docker:publish
```

After that I created a 2 folders:

my project (MyApp) folder with two files:

### controller.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: MyApp
  labels:
    name: MyApp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    name: MyApp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: MyApp
        version: 0.1.4
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: MyApp
        #this is the image artifactory
        image: docker-docker-release.someartifactory.com/MyApp:0.1.4
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: myCompany-artifactory
```

### service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: MyApp
  labels:
    name: MyApp
spec:
  # if your cluster supports it, uncomment the following to automatically create
  # an external load-balanced IP for the frontend service.
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    # the port that this service should serve on
  - port: 9000
  selector:
    name: MyApp
```

And I have another folder for my artifactory (Kind : Secret).

Now I created my pods with:

`kubectl create -f controller.yaml`

And now I have my pod running when I check in `kubectl get pods`.

Now, how do I access my pod from the browser? my project is a play project so I want to get to it from the browser...how do I expose it the simplest way?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

- The [Replication Controller](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/replication-controller/#what-is-a-replication-controller) sole responsibility is ensuring that the amount of pods with the given configuration are run on your cluster.
- The [Service](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/) is what is public (or internally) exposing your pods to other parts of the system (or the internet).

You should create your service with your yaml file (`kubectl create -f service.yaml`) which will create the service, selecting pods by the label selector `MyApp` for handling the load on the given port in your file (`9000`).

Afterwards look at the registered service with `kubectl get service` to see which endpoint (ip) is allocated for it.